# How to use parametised queries in cosmos contains method?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to CosmosDB and I am trying to use parameterized queries with `contains` method - but I keep getting an error in the console.

> Executed 'GetCustomers'
> Reason: ({"Errors":["Invalid query. Specified parameter name '@c.Surname' is invalid. Parameter names should be in the format of symbol '@' followed by a valid identifier. E.g. @param1"]});. {"Errors":["Invalid query. Specified parameter name '@c.Surname' is invalid.

Here is my code:

```
var query = $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.Surname, '@{surname}', true)";
var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query)
    .WithParameter("@c.Surname", surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name is incorrect.

And you should provide the parameter in the query

Your query should be:

```cs
query = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.Surname, @Surname, true)";
queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query).WithParameter("@Surname", surname);
```

Comment: this does not work - returns no values

Comment: If you copy the query, replace `@Surname` with the value, and run it in cosmos DB Data Explorer, does it able to return the value? After that test with `DECLARE @Surname NVARCHAR(MAX) ='Your value'` and with the parameterized query.